# SAPUI5 Select first item in list after rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5, master-detail

I have a Master-Detail application and I would like the first list item to be selected automatically once the application is loaded. I have tried the following solution but it does not work:

```
            onAfterRendering: function() {

              var oList = this.getView().byId("bankList");
              var aItems = oList.getItems("listItems");

              console.log(aItems);
                if (aItems.length) {
                    aItems[0].setSelected(true);
                 }
        }
```

The strange thing is that `aItems` seems to be empty even though it contains the correct details. Below is what is printed in the console when I `console.log(aItems)`:

The result of `console.log(aItems)`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that you are using a `sap.m.List`, You should use the [setSelectedItem()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/setSelectedItem) function, that receives the Item object as parameter.

Furthermore I recommend you to avoid using the `onAfterRendering` lifecycle method, to keep the lifecycle clean. There are usually many items that you can use, for example `updateFinished` for sap.m.List

Here the snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize_plus' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m' data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
      <List items="{/options}" mode="SingleSelect" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
        <StandardListItem title="{value}"></StandardListItem>
      </List>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>


  <script>
    // define a new (simple) Controller type
    sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
      onUpdateFinished: function(oEvent) {
        var oList = oEvent.getSource();
        var aItems = oList.getItems();
        oList.setSelectedItem(aItems[0])
      }
    });



    /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
    // create some dummy JSON data
    var data = {
      options: [{
        key: '1',
        value: 'option 1'
      }, {
        key: '2',
        value: 'option 2'
      }, {
        key: '3',
        value: 'option 3'
      }]
    };
    var oJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oJSONModel.setData(data);

    // instantiate the View
    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({
      viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

    myView.setModel(oJSONModel);
    // put the View onto the screen
    myView.placeAt('content');
  </script>

</head>

<body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! using onUpdateFinished has helped with the array being empty, it is now populated but oList.setSelectedItem(aItems[0]) is still not selecting the item after the initial load unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, that was due to an unrelated error. Your solution worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!